# Store value to Shared Preferences in a service class FirebaseInstanceIDService

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to store type of user string in Shared Preferences in an Activity, but when i try to `getString` from Shared Preferences in a service class in this case myFirebaseInstanceIDService it keeps giving me a `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference` error.

Here is where i am putting the value

```
btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterTutorActivity.this, ChooseSub.class));
            SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            sharedPref.edit().putString("Type", "Tutor").apply();
            signUpTutor();
        }
    });
```

and in myFirebaseInstanceIDService

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

private String type;
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    super.onTokenRefresh();
    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
    {

        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }
}

public void sendRegistrationToServer(String refreshedToken)
{
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    type = sharedPref.getString("Type", "");
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(type).child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
            .child("tokenID").setValue(refreshedToken);
}
}
```

I don't really now what i'm doing wrong with the Shared Preferences?

Comment: at which line you are getting this error?

Comment: try to use 'SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());' instead of 'SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);'

Comment: the error occurs on line SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Comment: and using getApplicationContext() doesnt work

Comment: make sure value of context isn't null

Comment: what happens if it is null, what should i do?

Comment: use activity's context instead. for example `MainActivity.this`

Comment: i cant pass values to FireabseInstanceIDService

Comment: `FireabseInstanceIDService` is fine you are getting error in button click listener right?

Comment: no im getting the error in FirebaseInstanceIDService at SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

Comment: instead of `this` `getApplicationContext()` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the token in Shared Preferences until you app is ready to consume it:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.edit().putString("Type", "Tutor");     
editor.commit();
signUpTutor();
```

You can request for the token like this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Type", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      String  type = sharedPref.getString("Type", null);
```

Comment: i cant use the bottom code because its a service class

Comment: Oh. My bad! Please check again

Comment: also sens the top code is going to be used in an actual activity what should i replace for getActivity()

Comment: `getActivity()` is your class context

Comment: i cant getActivity in a Activity and a new error came up

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: You can remove it and leave it like this `getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: I have added this line `getSharedPreferences( getPackageName() + "_preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);` check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a class to make `SharedPreferences` operations easy. i am sharing it here hope it will help you out.

```
public class PreferenceUtils {

    private SharedPreferences pref;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    public PreferenceUtils(Context context) {
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    }

    public void setPrefrences(String key, String value) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setPrefrences(String key, int value) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void setPrefrences(String key, boolean value) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public String getPrefrence(String key, String Default) {
        return pref.getString(key, Default);
    }

    public int getPrefrence(String key, int Default) {
        return pref.getInt(key, Default);
    }

    public boolean getPrefrence(String key, boolean Default) {
        return pref.getBoolean(key, Default);
    }

    public void deletePref(String[] key) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++)
            editor.remove(key[i]);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public void deletePref(String key) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        editor.remove(key);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

now where ever you want to use `SharedPreferences`, just initialize this class there.

for Activity,

```
PreferenceUtils utils = new PreferenceUtils(classname.this);
```

for Fragment,

```
PreferenceUtils utils = new PreferenceUtils(getActivity());
```

for service,

```
PreferenceUtils utils = new PreferenceUtils(getApplicationContext());
```

now for saving values you simply have to use object of PreferenceUtils class,

for example in your case,

```
utils.setPrefrences("Type", "Tutor");
```

and you can easily get value with that object too,

```
utils.getPrefrence("Type", null);
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you for this class, but for some reason i keep getting the same error now on the line of assigning the context to the getDefaultSharedPreferences in the class constructor "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference"

Comment: is there something i need to have in my android manifest for shared preferences, because everytim i try to get a context from a service class i get null

Comment: instead of `sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` try `sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());`

Comment: in manifest you just have to declare service class. and i guess you already have did it.

Comment: now getApplicationContext() error 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: Thank you for this code it worked for me and i created a MyApplication class to get my getApplictionContext

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i figured out my problem thanks to everyone. I created a MyApplication class that extends Application and created a getContext method. And now it works. Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score -2):

While Writing data in shared preferences use commit() instead of apply()

```
   sharedPref.edit().putString("Type", "Tutor").commit();
```